# Doxygen Ignoring Some .h Files

Tags: xcode, documentation, doxygen

UPDATE 2: The issue seems to be stemming from the files themselves, and not the contents.  I've tried, across multiple repos, duplicating the broken files from the ground up (new file, copy-paste contents, rename, etc) and they work as expected with Doxygen.

UPDATE: It seems that all of the "broken" .h files are being saved as class_.html while working .h files are interface_.html.  Strikes me as related.

Trying to set up Doxygen for my Xcode project and for some reason it is ignoring the .h file in one of my repos.

The basic structure of the project is 1 central repo with a handful of private CocoaPods being pulled in either from the local copy or the external repo, depending on which is more recent.  Other pods projects, when run against Doxygen, generate documentation just fine.  This one does not.  I've tried it with a variety of configurations (EXTRACT_ALL, EXTRACT_STATIC, etc. etc.) to no avail.

When run on the following .h file, no documentation is generated and the only thing I see is "The documentation for this class was generated from the following file:", with the .m file following; clicking on that just shows some static string constants and the imports, still no method headers.

One thing I noticed is that if I set EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS to YES then it works...but that would imply that I am NOT defining methods in my .h, which is definitely untrue.

Am I missing something?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FinderAuthApiProtocol.h>
#import <AuthCredentials.h>

//Keys to name persisted objects
extern NSString *const kCarrierAuthCredentialsPersistName;
extern NSString *const kFinderAuthCredentialsPersistName;
extern NSString *const kLastLoggedInUserName;

@interface CommonAuthManager : NSObject
/**
 *  Returns the singleton object for CommonAuthManager, or creates one if necessary
 *
 *  @return pointer to the singleton instance
 */
+ (CommonAuthManager *)sharedInstance;

/**
 *  @brief Performs carrier-agnostic authenticaton
 *
 *  This method is called by the UI to perform authentication with a user's
 *    username and password combination.  The carrier-specific implementation of
 *    Network's FinderAuthApiProtocol determines the precise behavior but as far
 *    as the manager is concerned it doesn't matter; it just calls auth and waits
 *    for results
 *  
 *  @param userID - the user's ID (i.e. phone number, username, email, etc)
 *  @param password - the user's password
 *  @param stayLoggedIn - toggled value for refreshig auth tokens or not
 *  @param block - block for completion
 **/
+ (void)authWithUserID:(NSString *)userID
            andPassword:(NSString *)password
        andStayLoggedIn:(bool)stayLoggedIn
              withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))block;

/**
 *  Determines if current user is allowed to say logged in (bypass explicit login screen)
 *
 *  YES if all the following criteria are met:
 *    Current user must exist in persistence store
 *    Current user last login attempt must have succeeded
 *    Current user must be allowed to stay logged in
 *
 *  @param error return error
 *
 *  @return Returns YES if user is allowed to stay logged in
 */
+ (BOOL)isUserAllowedToStayLoggedIn:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error;

/**
 *  Abstracted-away selector for the LLCommonAuthManager's finder API credentials
 **/
+ (AuthCredentials *)finderCredentials;

/**
 *  Abstracted-away selector for the LLCommonAuthManager's carrier API credentials
 *
 *  NOTE: Functionality across carriers varies.  For <XXX> this object will have
 *    the auth token, while for <YYY> it will be the username and password
 *    they originally authed with.
 **/
+ (AuthCredentials *)credentials;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Doxygen expects a newline at the bottom of the file.

Who knew.